# Load a pdf into S3 using User Defined Java Class in Pentaho

Tags: java, amazon-s3, pentaho

```java
import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
import com.amazonaws.SdkClientException;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class UploadObject {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Regions clientRegion = Regions.US_EAST_1;

    String fileObjKeyName = "N.pdf";

    String fileName = "C:\\home\\aws\\N.pdf";

    //To Test the File Upload

    String accessKeyId = "AKIAZGSMNGVXXXZ73VXE";

    String secretAccessKey = "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";

    String bucketName = "fioprod-s3-addon-us-east-12";

    try {

      final BasicAWSCredentials basicAWSCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKeyId, secretAccessKey);

      //This code expects that you have AWS credentials set up per:

      // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/setup-credentials.html

      AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
          .withRegion(clientRegion)
          .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(basicAWSCredentials))
          .build();

      // Upload a file as a new object with ContentType and title specified.

      PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileObjKeyName, new File(fileName));

      ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();

      metadata.setContentType("plain/text");

      metadata.addUserMetadata("title", "someTitle");

      request.setMetadata(metadata);

      s3Client.putObject(request);

    } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {

      // The call was transmitted successfully, but Amazon S3 couldn't process

      // it, so it returned an error response.

      e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (SdkClientException e) {

      // Amazon S3 couldn't be contacted for a response, or the client

      // couldn't parse the response from Amazon S3.

      e.printStackTrace();

    }

  }

}
```

The above code works fine to load pdf file into S3 when I run it from IntelliJ IDE. I want this code to move to Pentaho "User Defined Class", when I do that it throws error - " Imported class "com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider" could not be loaded"

How do I resolve that? My ultimate goal is to load a .pdf or .zip file into S3 using pentaho.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your have written nice code which is working as well. You just need to keep aws-java-sdk jar to your data-integration/lib location.

You can download sdk jar file from [Here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-bundle/1.11.869/aws-java-sdk-bundle-1.11.869.jar)

You can look my KTR also from [Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1j3pJZb1sYh858PZC9-He4uh-avnhe8X8?usp=sharing)   where I have included your code and make small changes to workable your code in User-defined-java-class in PDI

```
import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
import com.amazonaws.SdkClientException;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public boolean processRow(StepMetaInterface smi, StepDataInterface sdi) throws KettleException{
    Object[] r = getRow();
 
 if (r == null) {
        setOutputDone();
        return false;
    }



    Regions clientRegion = Regions.US_EAST_1;

    String fileObjKeyName = "N.pdf";

    String fileName = "C:\\home\\aws\\N.pdf";

    //To Test the File Upload

    String accessKeyId = "AKIAZGSMNGVXXXZ73VXE";

    String secretAccessKey = "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";

    String bucketName = "fioprod-s3-addon-us-east-12";
    

      final BasicAWSCredentials basicAWSCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKeyId, secretAccessKey);

      //This code expects that you have AWS credentials set up per:

      // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/setup-credentials.html

      AmazonS3 s3Client = (AmazonS3)AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(clientRegion).withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(basicAWSCredentials)).build();

      // Upload a file as a new object with ContentType and title specified.

      PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileObjKeyName, new File(fileName));

      ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();

      metadata.setContentType("plain/text");

      metadata.addUserMetadata("title", "someTitle");

      request.setMetadata(metadata);

      s3Client.putObject(request);

   
    putRow(data.outputRowMeta, r);
     return true;

}
```

Comment: If I want to bring the following lines from the previous step, what should be the right approach? Tried with DataGrid, not working yet:                                                                                                                   
String fileObjKeyName = "N.pdf";
String fileName = "C:\\home\\aws\\N.pdf";                                                                 
String bucketName = "fioprod-s3-addon-us-east-12";

Comment: you can check my job and KTR here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1FSYKag6GC_hikWK9iH_ARd1pYmPGfmgi?usp=sharing

Comment: As in your MainJob , you already set all the variables; So it will be good if you read those variable from your S3 transformation. Yes, please use "String getFilename = getVariable("FILENAME");"  in your 'User Define Java Class' step will work definitely.

Comment: Eventually, I will move all variables to the main job, when these 2 variables work as expected; I have used  "String fileObjKeyName = getVariable("FILENAME");
    String fileName = getVariable("LOCALDIR").concat(fileObjKeyName);" When I execute the 
 job, it does not fail, but no file is uploaded into S3; https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1FSYKag6GC_hikWK9iH_ARd1pYmPGfmgi

Comment: No need step "Get rows from result" . Remove this step and run the process. And change variable scope to "Valid in the Java Virtual Machine" in MainJob. I think all will be ok

Comment: Also, you can look below process. where you found how I transfer variable from job to transformation and use in 'User defined Java class' step. "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64161359/lookup-pentaho-data-integration/64165419#64165419"

Comment: Is not the above implementation is path style request which is deprecated by Amazon: https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html#virtual-hosted-style-access