# lookup_Pentaho data Integration

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

I have two files (App.csv and Acess.csv)

1. App.csv has one column called Application
   Application
   App-A

   App-B
2. Access.csv contains 3 columns (Application, entitlement, userid)

   ```
       Application, entitlement, userid

       App-A,ent-A,user1
       App-A,ent-B,user1
       App-B,ent-c,user2
       App-B,ent-d,user1
       App-C,ent-c,user2
       App-C,ent-d,user1
   ```
3. I need extract all the App-A and App-B details if it matches Application file column and output should like be below

   ```
       App-A,ent-A,user1                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
       App-A,ent-B,user1
       App-B,ent-c,user2
       App-B,ent-d,user1
   ```
4. i tried using stream-lookup but it's only giving one row per App instead of all rows belongs to App-A and App-B

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have prepare a solution for you [Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1wRQOO9m7OSKtFBo3DVQcUUGmyPMd8u55?usp=sharing)

I used user-define-java-class to compare the value.

1. RunTrans.ktr: I take app.csv input from here and make data in one row.
2. ForOnlyLoop.kjb: This is just for passing data to next transformation.
3. CopmareAndResult.ktr: I take access.csv input from here and compare result, if value match then return row otherwise return nothing.

Please let me know if its ok with you.

**Another Solution:-**
You can get same solution using ETL metadata Injection step from [Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Z_sM5H4qPB_S0J8zL79N2pWg_0TDHog_?usp=sharing)

1. MetaData.ktr:- Take App.csv input and pass value to compare ktr.
2. Compare.ktr: Take access.csv input and compare value with 'switch/case' step. I have provided switch- case comparison value from MataData.ktr step.

Comment: Thank you. your solution worked for me...I also tried it using fuzzy logic where app names from app.csv matched all the app columns in access.csv and then i used filter rows to filter only matches rows.

Comment: I have create another solution for lookup. Where I have used ETL-Metadata_injection.