# Connect to Minio S3 with Pentaho Data Integration CE

Tags: amazon-s3, pentaho-spoon, minio, vfs

Is there a way to connect to Google cloud storage with PDI Community version?

I have looked at VFS connection, but no connection types are listed in the the drop down while creating a new VFS connection.

In the PDI 9.1 we use, this list is complete empty

Comment: If you are looking to upload file to AWS S3 then you can follow this  url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64068437/load-a-pdf-into-s3-using-user-defined-java-class-in-pentaho/64074230#64074230

Comment: For VFS connection, you need to add the connection type/setting at first. See url https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/9.0/Products/Connecting_to_Virtual_File_Systems

Comment: Or you can use 'S3 File Output' step to upload file in S3

Comment: are VFS connections supported in the community edition at all?
I experience the same, no connection types are listed in the the drop down, but in the enterprise edition they show up fine.

Answer (score 2):

Pentaho PDI 9.3 CE supports Amazon/Minio S3 but non of the other VFS Options, they should be available in Enterprise. I needed Azure Blob support and switched to Apache HOP. Well, HOP supports all kind of VFS connections including Azure BUT only Amazon S3, no Minio or other S3 implementation. So in the end i might have to get my S3 Data with Pentaho PDI and push them to Azure with Apache HOP :-)
There is no official documentation on this.

Pentaho PDI Example VFS connection Summary to S3 Storage provided by Netypp Storage GRID looks like this:

---

General Settings:

Connection Name: yourConnectionName
Connection Type: Amazon S3 / Minio
Connection Details
Access Key: yourAccessKey
Secret Key: yourSecretKey
Region: Default
Credential File: No

Profile Name: 
Endpoint: https://s3.yourDomain
PathStyle Access: true
Signature Version: AWSS3V4SignerType
Default S3 Connection: true
Connection Type: Minio

---

Took me quite some time to find out the value for the Signature Version!

Check [this AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/specifying-kms-encryption.html) out, inside **Presigned URLs** of **Using the AWS SDKs** part.

Note that to fill Endpoint field with Minio API URL, which ends in port 9000 if you set up a local Minio server.

Also, checkbox **PathStyle Access** and **Default S3 Connection** are optional.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).